# Is there a way to transform a point in the initial photo coordinates after a crop with cropperjs

Tags: geometry, cropperjs

I use cropperjs to crop some image, I keep in database the result of getData method who return values in white on the picture.

```
{x, y, width, height, rotate}
```

My users can place points on the cropped image in the red space, is there a way to retrieve the coordinates of the point in the blue space?

The crop ratio is free so there is no relation between original image ratio and crop ratio and I don't have the original image size.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first get coordinates in bounding box

```
bbx = redx + x
bby = redy + y
```

Now make rotation about bounding box center

```
bluex = bbcenterx + (bbx - bbcenterx) * Cos(rotate) + (bby - bbcentery) * Sin(rotate)
bluey = bbcentery - (bbx - bbcenterx) * Sin(rotate) + (bby - bbcentery) * Cos(rotate)
```

If you don't know bounding box size, but know initial picture width `w` and height `h`, you can calculate bounding box center

```
bbcenterx = (w * Abs(Sin(rotate)) + h * Abs(Cos(rotate))) / 2
bbcenterx = (w * Abs(Cos(rotate)) + h * Abs(Sin(rotate))) / 2
```

Comment: So without the original image size there is no way to do what i want?

Comment: I cannot say for now. Quick modelling shows (visually) close coordinates for some rectangle sizes, but perhaps they are not exactly similar.

Comment: Finaly I was able to retrive the blue coordinates with some matrix transform. You were right the size of the original image is mandatory. Thanks to putting me in the right direction.